# On the planet, or in the planet

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

I know the typical usage is *on* but I'm wondering what's more comprehensive:

> The number of species in the planet

or

> The number of species on the planet

Comment: Do the species you refer to live exclusively under the surface?

Comment: What makes you think the typical usage is inaccurate?

Comment: I'm referring to the total count of species types

Comment: I'm not saying it's inaccurate. Maybe, instead of accuracy, I'm looking for which is the most comprehensive. I saw it on Wikipedia phrased that way and it immediately looked odd, but then thought, it's not wrong as such.

Comment: I have voted to close as there is no context or a full sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The number of species on the planet, would be correct. On and in play an important role here, as the species don't live in the planet, but on. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from linked references to support your claim.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of the iWeb corpus says that *on* is more frequent than *in* by a ratio of 100:1. If you're going for something more all-encompasing, ***sharing*** the planet or ***inhabiting*** the planet are good choices. For something with a bit more flair, ***occupying*** the planet or ***enjoying*** the planet might work.